# Calligraphic style with KP fonts

Tags: xetex, kpfonts

Recently I started to use the KPFonts-OT with my beamer presentations. In particular, I use
the option `Style=mathcal (+ss01)` so that the commands `\mathcal{}` and `\mathscr{}` print

[image]

instead of

[image]

which is the default behavior. However I've noticed that letter "M" is unaffected by this setting, being printed by default.

This is a MWE (compile with xelatex):

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\setmainfont{KpSans}
\setsansfont{KpSans}
\setmonofont{KpMono}
\setmathfont{KpMath-Sans.otf}[StylisticSet={1,2,4}]
% \setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}[range={cal,bfcal},StylisticSet=1]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test frame}
This is a test with a formula below:
\[
  \mathcal{ABCM}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I get is

[image]

I can circumvent this problem by adding to the preamble

`\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}[range={cal,bfcal},StylisticSet=1]`

In summary, is this a bug related to the KpMath sans font? Is there another better way of fixing this problem?

Comment: As far as I can see there is no `ss02` feature in KPMath-Sans. Anyway, the workaround seems sensible until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Yes, looking in fontforge, it is clear that the M is missing in `ss01`. I would contact the font maintainer, he is usually very quick to fix such things.

Comment: I am the maintainer. I'll have a look,keep tuned…

Comment: The bug is fixed, I'll push a new version (0.52) to CTAN this afternoon, it should be available in TeX distribution tomorrow or after-tomorrow. Thanks for your report! Btw. the `ss02` feature does not make sense with KpMath-Sans: the blackboard bold capitals are  sans-serif by default.

Comment: I've updated texllve, tested the new version of kpfonts-otf and now everything is working as expected. Thank you very much!